# Random variable - what does mean the condition in definition

Tags: probability, statistics

The definition of random variable in my book is:
This is a function $X: \Omega \rightarrow R$, such that $ \{ \omega : X(\omega) < x\} \in S $
where $S$ is sigma-algebra, $\Omega$ is sample space and $\omega$ is single event.

What does mean the condition $ \{ \omega : X(\omega) < x\} \in S $ ?

Comment: It may be easier to think of it this way (which is equivalent but does not require the scary term "sigma algebra"):  A random variable $X$ is a function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and we assume $X$ has as CDF function $F_X(x) = P[X\leq x]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  [The condition $\{\omega : X(\omega) \leq x\} \in S$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is the same as saying a CDF function exists, and this condition holds if and only if $\{\omega : X(\omega) < x\} \in S$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.]

Answer (score 4):

For random variables on many sample spaces $\Omega$, it is not possible to define a probability measure $P$ on every subset of $\Omega$ in a consistent way. The cure is to speak of probabilities of *events* which must be subsets of some sigma-algebra $S$ of subsets of $\Omega$. A useful random variable involves subsets of $S.$ The condition you ask about ensures we don't try to find the probability of an event $\{\omega: X(\omega) < x\}$ that does not have a probability.

Note: This technical requirement, for measurability in the definition of a random variable, is not an issue for random variables in ordinary applications. So don't expect anyone to give you an example of a subset of $\Omega$ that causes trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The $\sigma$-algebra $S$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ which satisfies certain properties. The condition $\{\omega : X(\omega) < x\} \in S$ means that the set $\{\omega : X(\omega) < x\}$ belongs to $S$ for all $x$.

Why is this condition needed? If the sample space $\Omega$ is finite then this condition isn't needed: you can (and usually should) take $S$ to consist of *all* subsets of $\Omega$. However, when $\Omega$ is infinite, you could run into trouble with non-measurable sets. Let $A$ be some non-measurable set on $\Omega = [0,1]$. You can construct a function $X\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ which is the indicator function of $A$. What is the expectation of $X$? What is the probability that $X < 1/2$? It is difficult to answer these questions since $A$ is not measurable. If you allow arbitrary $X$ then you run into paradoxes stemming from these issues. Hence we define a random variable to be measurable in the sense that $\Pr[X < x]$ is defined for all $x$.

Comment: Non measurable set mean - A set that we can't measure number of set elements? I'm not a math student, therefore don't blame me if i ask a basic question.

Comment: Look it up. Technically I mean a set which is non measurable with respect to Lebesgue measure. You can find more information by searching for the phrase *non measurable set*.