# What does the definition of a random variable actually mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am taking a probability class, and my textbook has defined the random variable in the context of a cumulative distribution function (CDF):

"A random variable has the property that sets of the form $\{ \omega: X(\omega) \le c \}$ belong to the  event space $F$."

1. What does this definition mean? Is it just trying to make explicit that the random variable depends on another variable $\omega$?
2. What is $\omega$?
3. What's the significance of $c$ here?

P.S.: I'm aware that [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197339/random-variable-what-does-mean-the-condition-in-definition) answers a similar question, but it's in the context of sigma algebra which my class does not touch upon. I'm honestly a little confused by the answers on that page.

I'd really appreciate if you could answer my questions in plain, simple English that my engineer brain could comprehend. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To acquire a solid comprehension of the technical definition of a random variable requires measure theory, which does require sigma algebras.

I will try to give a relatively non-technical definition. First note that we require a set $\Omega$, called the *sample space*, which roughly contains everything that could possibly happen in our experiment. The elements $\omega \in \Omega$ are the individual outcomes that can occur.

A random variable is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ that has a special property that helps make rigorous probability theory work. (This special property is called being *measurable*, which you can look up if you want to.) So given any outcome of the experiment $\omega$, you get $X(\omega)$, which is a real number.

A CDF is a function $F(c) = P\big(\{\omega \in \Omega \colon X(\omega) \leq c \} \big)$, or more informally $P(X \leq c$), that gives the probability that the random variable $X$ is less than or equal to $c$. Specifically, the CDF is a function of $c$. (In formal probability theory, the CDF is the fundamental object from which pdfs and pmfs are derived.)

Aside: note that there is no randomness in the definition of a random variable. It's just a function.

Comment: Is $\omega$ an event? So for example, if I rolled a dice, and the event is "I get a one," what would $X(\omega)$ look like then?

Comment: Events are a little bit different. They're *sets* of outcomes. So, rolling a one would be an event, but rolling any number bigger than 3 is also an event. As for $X(\omega)$, roughly speaking it can be whatever you want it to be. It could just be the number on the face, or it could be double the number on the face, or the sine of the number on the face, or it could be 1 if you roll an even number and 0 if you roll an odd number.

Comment: The random variable is just a function of the outcome $\omega$. Most functions that you can think of would probably meet the technical definition of a random variable.

Comment: So, would you say a function like $X(\omega) = \omega^2 -2\omega +1$ constitutes a random variable? And the $P(X)$ cares more about the likelihood of $X$ landing on a particular value rather than a specific $\omega$ occurring?

Comment: @notelonsmustache Yes, that would be a random variable, because it's continuous. The probability of a specific value depends: in discrete probability it can be positive, but in continuous probability it's always zero.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the technicalities ($\sigma$-algebras etc), you can say that a random variable is a numerical quantity that depends on the outcome in a probability model.  So the probability model will give probabilities to events such as "the random variable $X$ has a value $\le c$".

When you do go into the technicalities, it turns out that not all sets of outcomes might be assigned probabilities, so not all functions on the outcomes will be random variables.  That's where you need to talk about $\sigma$-algebras.  But in practice you'll never meet a function on the outcomes that is not a random variable.